# Twitter Omniauth Login on Heroku with Custom Domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, omniauth

I'm trying to set up Omniauth login for Twitter/FB. I created my own authentication system 
 and was able to get my Twitter log in to work on localhost following http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth.

However, upon deploying to Heroku, I get the following error when I try to log in via Twitter on production:

```
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
```

Heroku logs:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/auth/twitter"):
```

This should be handled by omniauth automatically.

I changed my callback url (with a custom domain) to `http://www.mysite.com/auth/twitter/callback` on my Twitter Dev page. This still does not fix the production log in, but development log in still works.

I've looked through several stackoverflow questions and it seems like there is some issue with Heroku custom domains and Omniauth. There are several solutions where people use devise, but I'm not using devise.

I've also added the key onto heroku using: `heroku config:add CONSUMER_KEY=key CONSUMER_SECRET=secret --app myapp`

Does anyone have any suggestions? I can also post relevant code if needed.

Comment: Can you paste what you have in your route file

Comment: the url that is failing is /auth/twitter not /auth/twitter/callback 

Why are you being directed to /auth/twitter instead of /auth/twitter/callback?

Comment: I was able to solve this problem.

Comment: how?? i have the same problem